# Stylelint will not ignore "custom-property-pattern" rule

Tags: git, stylelint, husky, lint-staged

I am trying to run `stylelint --fix` as part of a Husky hook with `npx lint-staged`.

However, it keeps failing because we are using snake case for our in-house css variables.  There are also some kebab case variables in our scss from Bootstrap and the like.

```
npx lint-staged
✔ Preparing lint-staged...
✔ Hiding unstaged changes to partially staged files...
❯ Running tasks for staged files...
  ❯ package.json — 9 files
    ❯ *.{scss, css} — 2 files
      ✖ stylelint --fix [FAILED]
    ✔ *.{js,ts,json,html,scss,css} — 6 files
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks. [SKIPPED]
↓ Skipped because of errors from tasks. [SKIPPED]
✔ Reverting to original state because of errors...
✔ Cleaning up temporary files...

✖ stylelint --fix:

client/src/sass/designsystem/primeng/_image.scss
 2:25  ✖  Expected custom property name "--border_color" to be kebab-case  custom-property-pattern

1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

So I don't want this to flag as an error or have stylelint try to "fix" css variables: I want to ignore them. So I added this to my `.stylelintrc`:

```
    "custom-property-pattern": null,
```

But it still persists. What am I missing here?  I just want to ignore the custom properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `.stylelintrc` file:

```
"selector-class-pattern": null
```